# How to set primary key when using many-to-many-polymorphic-relations in laravel ORM qloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using  Many To Many Polymorphic Relations in laravel.
When I read the docs [many-to-many-polymorphic-relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations),it says

> a blog Post and Video model could share a polymorphic relation to a Tag model.

here is the table structure:

```
posts  
    id - integer   
    name - string    

videos  
    id - integer  
    name - string  

tags      
    id - integer  
    name - string  


taggables

    tag_id - integer
    taggable_id - integer
    taggable_type - string
```

I always set a primary key for the tables.
In this case should I add an id column as primary key or I dont need to set a primary key?
Is there any conventions?

Comment: You could make a composite primary key out of the 3 columns in `taggables`.

Comment: @devk thanks .I get you after I see the first answer.It would be perfect if you can be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id auto-increment ID is not very useful in table `taggables`. For `taggables` eloquent, you can disable primary key, timestamps:

```
/**
 * primaryKey 
 * 
 * @var integer
 * @access protected
 */
protected $primaryKey = null;

/**
 * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $incrementing = false;

/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'taggables';

/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $timestamps = false;
```

To create primary key, 3 columns composite primary keys can be created.

And you may need to consider the **column order** when you created the **composite primary keys**.

It depends on the use case of the application. If it always queries what tags a post / video have, this primary key `PRIMARY KEY(taggable_type, taggable_id, tag_id)` should be created. If, another case, it always queries what posts / videos a tag have, this primary key `PRIMARY KEY(tag_id, taggable_type, taggable_id)` should be created.

See also: [Many-to-Many Mapping table](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)